# How to get the list of all loggers in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to get the list of all loggers with this code

```
 LoggerContext logContext = LoggerContext.getContext(false);
    Configuration config = logContext.getConfiguration();
    writeLoggers(config.getLoggers().values(), response);
```

Below part does not seem to e returning all the loggers, it returns a very few. I have more than 600 loggers in the list.

```
config.getLoggers().values()
```

When I use below **logContext** **getLoggers()** method, It returns all the loggers class, So I am wondering what is the correct way to get the loggers in log4j2, the **Configuration** **getLoggers()** Method does not seem to be working for me. For me, the problem is one is returning a map of type **Logger** and other is **LoggerConfig**. My entire code is using LoggerConfig that is why I wanted to use the **config.getLoggers()** method

```
logContext.getLoggers()
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you review http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html. Unlike other logging frameworks, Log4J separates the logging configuration from the Loggers the application obtains. So when you ask for loggers from the configuration you are going to get the LoggerConfig objects, which normally there are only a few of. If you want the list of loggers the application is using you want to get the Loggers from the LoggerContext. Be aware that updating the Loggers directly is not recommended. You should update the configuration instead and then call the updateLoggers method of the LoggerContext to propagate your changes.